# When did the piggies learn about the Demosthenian Hierarchy of Exclusion

Tags: orson-scott-card, chronology, speaker-for-the-dead

In the beginning of chapter 4 of Speaker for the Dead, in Pipo's notes it says this :

> As for what they call us, they do use human, of course, but they have also taken to using the new Demosthenian Hierarchy of Exclusion. They refer to humans as framlings, and to pequeninos of other tribes as utlannings. Oddly, though, they refer to themselves as ramen, showing that they either misunderstand the hierarchy or view themselves from the human perspective! And—quite an amazing turn—they have several times referred to the females as varelse!

But in chapter 9, in Miro's thoughts, there is this:

> I wish, Ouanda, that you had not explained Demosthenes’ Hierarchy of Exclusion to them.

Now, Ouanda wasn't born until after the incident with Pipo. So when did they learn about the Hierarchy?

Just wanted to also point out that the Hierarchy had been published right before Ender left Trondheim:

> Ender was startled for a moment to hear her use that word; but of course Demosthenes’ latest book had been published twenty-two years ago, and distributed through the Hundred Worlds by ansible.

Comment: ...[ramen](http://www.maruchan.com/index_images/bot_lft.jpg)?

Comment: @izkata - with spicy sauce?

Answer (score 2):

I rather think you've answered your own question. The idea is that Demosthenes (e.g. Ender's sister, Valentine) had **only just** come up with the "Hierarchy of Exclusion" shortly before Ender left Trondheim yet by the time he lands (some 22 years later in realtime but mere days later in relative time) this hierarchy has become accepted *throughout* the [Starway Congress](http://ansible.wikia.com/wiki/Starways_Congress) planets.

Obviously it's worth mentioning that because Ender and Valentine have recently been planet-hopping, her "new" philosophical idea has actually been some 30-40 years of subjective time in the making which explains how both both Ouanda and Pipo could have separately taught it to different groups of Pequinos.

Ender makes this point himself (e.g. that he's a man outside of time) when he tells Novhina about the sacrifice he's made;

> **Ender :** *We don’t measure starflight in kilometers, Dona Ivanova. We measure it
>   in years*

What's interesting is not only how the author uses the concept of the growth of her ideas to show that Ender's travelling has isolated him from his sister but also the fact that it **instantly reveals** to Ender that the Pequinos are being educated in **cutting edge** natural philosophy of a decidely heretical nature.

Comment: I don't think you're addressing my point at all.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. How could Ouanda have taught them something that appears in Pipo's notes? I'm assuming that the entire concept of the hierarchy didn't spring fully-formed from Valentine's head in a single afternoon. She may have codified it finally, but it was probably the product of decades of philosophical thought by hundreds of people in a thousand worlds

Comment: My point is that two different times are given for when they learnt about it.

Comment: The piggies he's referring to are all dead/planted by the time Ouanda is teaching them.

Comment: @ike - I've edited to more closely address the issue.

Comment: Are you saying that the piggies didn't teach their offspring?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12676/discussion-between-richard-and-ike)